# How to compare date() in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two date variables. How do I convert $time back to the original date() in order to compare two $time variables?

```
$time = date('H:i');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun fact about date/times: If you keep them in a big-endian format (ie. the left-most item is the biggest) then they can be sorted as strings.

Example: `Y-m-d` ([aside](https://xkcd.com/1179/)) will give dates like `2014-02-19`, which you can compare as a string to another date, such as `2014-01-29`, to get the result (in this case, the first is bigger).

Time: `H:i` is big-endian (hours are bigger than minutes), and the result is you can compare things like `14:23` to `09:12` successfully.

PITFALL: Always use the zero-padded versions of things like day number and hours, otherwise the comparison will go wrong for values less than 10. Also, you cannot use 12-hour time unless you put the AM/PM *before* the Hour in your format (because that will preserve endianness).

I use this a lot to compare dates ^_^

Comment: So how do I actually compare the two? 2014-02-19 & 2014-02-29

Comment: `<`, `>` and `==`, same as anything else.

Comment: Really? Dang thats nice!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `diff()` function from the DateTime class.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the format of date is 05:43, 13:21, 23:59...etc Would that still work?

Comment: For date/time comparison you could just use the times that you have. If you want to get the full date from your `date('H:i')` function, you could use `strtotime(date('H:i'))` to get the timestamp of that generated time.